# how to find this grammar in CNF

Tags: context-free-grammar

I need help solve the grammar to CNF : `S->SS|(S)|e`

I looked at the steps for getting it to CNF but my problem is How to solve it for a grammar with () coz the grammar becomes illegal

Anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be an equivalent grammar in CNF:

```
S -> SS|CB|e
A -> (
B -> )
C -> AS
```

**Edit:** for the grammar `S -> SS|(S)|ε`
first step in CNF is to remove ε (simplified to remove redundant rules)

```
S -> SS|S|(S)|()
```

next step is to remove unit productions. in this case you only have one production rule so we can just drop the UP since it would just add redundant rules.

```
S -> SS|(S)|()
```

final step is to add production rules to adhere to CNF (single terminal or exactly 2 variables):

```
S -> SS|CB|AB
A -> (
B -> )
C -> AS
```

remember that CNF removes 'ε' from the language generated by the grammer. otherwise the grammar is equivalent to the original.

Comment: Thank You but will the answer be correct if the grammar is S->SS|(S)|ε

Comment: @Shark why wouldn't it be? just replace 'e' with 'ε'.

Comment: I thought according for a grammar to be in CNF we have to eliminate lambda productions from it (eliminate ε rule)

Comment: @Shark you are correct. so do you want an answer for 'εe instead of 'e'? I forgot that ε is used as λ

Comment: Yes please,so the grammar is S->SS|(S)|λ

Comment: Thanks was really confused with (S).

Comment: @Shark no, problem. If your question is answered please close it. for future reference [CS stack exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) is a better place to ask questions like this.